# Trying to change a 2D list that is defined within class __init__

Tags: python

So I am making a game of Battleship and currently have a grid that is defined in the class **init** function. The size of the grid is square and gets its size from an argument as such:

```python
class Board:
    def __init__(self, size):
        self.size = size
        self._grid = [['.']*self.size]*self.size
```

So with self._grid, I plan to print out this 2D list. The problem I am having is replacing a '.' with a letter to represent a ship. So:

```python
    def add_ship(self):
        self._grid[1][5] = 'B' #this is to determine a Battleship with length of one for now. 

    def print(self):
        # prints out content within game board. 
        for i in range(self.size):
            for j in range(self.size):
                print(self._grid[i][j] +' ', end='')
```

With add_ship, I plan to change elements within the gird. With print, I want to print out the grid. The main problem is that it is not changing element [1][5], but instead changes the entire column. Any tips on another way to do this? Thanks!

Comment: ```self._grid = [['.'] * self.size for _ in range(self.size)]``` should work.

Comment: That works perfectly to print the grid of periods... yet now I do not know how to change and update the elements.

Comment: I think your ```add_ship(self)``` works perfectly.

Comment: Yeah I just got it working the way I intended! Hopefully things keep going smooth, thanks for the help.